# How to set a button, clickable, from another class?

Tags: android, android-button, android-dialogfragment

I have 2 Classes `MainActivity` and `DialogBox` and there is one button in my *activity_main.xml* which is initially not clickable. I want to make it clickable every time the user enters the correct username and password and then clicks *confrim* or the `setPositiveButton` in my dialog box.

Here is my cpde for MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button buttonSetting;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonSetting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSettings);
    }

    public void ShowDialog(View view) {
        DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();
        dialogBox.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog Box");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my DialogBox class:

```
public class DialogBox extends DialogFragment {
    private static String username = "admin";
    private static String password = "1234";
    String typeUsername;
    String typePassword;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View custom = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        final EditText editTextUsername = (EditText) custom.findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) custom.findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);            
        builder.setView(custom);

        typePassword = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        typeUsername = editTextUsername.getText().toString();

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Negative button was clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    typePassword = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                    typeUsername = editTextUsername.getText().toString();

                    if (typePassword.equals(password)
                      && typeUsername.equals(username)) 
                    {
                        View activity = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
                        Button buttonSettings = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.buttonSettings);
                        buttonSettings.setEnabled(true);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "correct!",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong input",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        });

        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: For a moment, please refer to [Android Dev | Passing events back to the dialog's host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents). You will need an interface to interact with your `Activity`.

Comment: what is your question here and whats going wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

you should always `listen` to the `user inputs` and change of text in `username` and `password` box. but the approach is quiet bad, when someone who tries to randomly enter text may know its correct login credentials easily. You can set `text listeners` in android

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonSetting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSettings);

// display the AlertDialog in your MainActivity
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

View custom = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
final EditText editTextUsername = (EditText) custom.findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) custom.findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);            
builder.setView(custom);


typePassword = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
typeUsername = editTextUsername.getText().toString();

builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Negative button was clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                typePassword = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                typeUsername = editTextUsername.getText().toString();

                if (typePassword.equals(password)
                        && typeUsername.equals(username)) 
                {
                    //this will perform buttonSetting click function 
                    buttonSetting.performClick();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "correct!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } 
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Wrong input",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

Dialog dialog = builder.create();

}
```